# Django マイグレーションについて

Tags: django

http://farewell-work.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/05/07/160824のチュートリアルに従ってアプリを作っています。

models.pyにテーブル作成の定義をし、いざpython manage.py makemigrationsをしようとしたら、INSTALLED_APPSにないのでは？というエラーがでたので、INSTALLED_APPSにアプリケーション名を追加したところ無事migrationsフォルダ直下に0001_initial.pyが作成されました。

以下が質問です。
Djangoのドキュメントにあるチュートリアルをやった時は、INSTALLED_APPSにアプリケーション名を追加するという作業はしませんでした。実際INSTALLED_APPSにpolls（チュートリアルのアプリ名）はありません。なぜそれでもmakemigrationsできたのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Djangoのドキュメントにあるチュートリアルをやった時は、INSTALLED_APPSにアプリケーション名を追加するという作業はしませんでした。実際INSTALLED_APPSにpolls（チュートリアルのアプリ名）はありません。なぜそれでもmakemigrationsできたのでしょうか？

質問者さんの隣で見ていたわけではないので確証はありませんが、次 ↓ のとおり Django 公式のチュートリアルには `makemigrations` の前に追加する手順が載っているので、質問者さんの記憶違いか何かではないでしょうか（通常は追加する必要があると思います）。

> To include the app in our project, we need to add a reference to its configuration class in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. The `PollsConfig` class is in the `polls/apps.py` file, so its dotted path is `'polls.apps.PollsConfig'`. Edit the `mysite/settings.py` file and add that dotted path to the INSTALLED_APPS setting.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models

もし記憶違いではなくて実際にそうなったということであれば、現象が再現できる一式のコードをご提示になると、より有益な回答がもらえやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。もう一度見直したところpolls.apps.PollsConfigというのがありました。pollsのみの文字列で入ってるという先入観から見逃してしまいました。くだらない質問にお時間取らせてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: いえ、ご返信ありがとうございます。なるほど、そういうことですね。確かに `'polls'` でページ内検索をしてもひっかからないので、見落としてしまっても仕方ない気もします。